# Why it returns null in a REST request

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

There is a functioning site on WordPress. And it has a database attached to it in PhpMyAdmin. The database has a table of records of user type. As shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW6pG.png), it has a place_id field. When I try to access this custom type using GET REST with the following query:

```
GET https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/orders/
```

I get a json file with information about all records of this type, but the place_id field of each record stores null. Am I right in assuming that REST in this case takes data from the database? Why does it return null then?

Comment: Hello Demmen and welcome to Stack Overflow, can you elaborate your question and add some code you trying to get the `place_id`

Comment: @WasimSayyed, hello. Tried to describe it in more detail.

Comment: Please read [mre]